# Getting length of binary column in snowflake using information schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

As the title suggests, I want to determine the length that I have specified while creating the column of type `BINARY` in Snowflake. I tried to get this information from `Information_Schema.COLUMNS` view. But on inspecting the result I did not see any columns that had this information. I thought `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` of this view might contain this info but it does not.

I am aware that I can also use `SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE <tab_name>` but for my requirement I only want to use the information_schema.

Is this information not stored in the `information_schema`?

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want this solution, but I will just put it here for "other people" looking for the same thing.

```
create table test.test.test_len(bin_10 binary(10), bin_200 binary(200) );

show columns in table test.test.test_len;

select 
    "column_name" as name
    ,parse_json("data_type"):length::number as len
from table(RESULT_SCAN());
```

| NAME | LEN |
| --- | --- |
| BIN_10 | 10 |
| BIN_200 | 200 |